# What is the best way to deal with library dependencies in android if you are working as a team?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-management, android-gradle-plugin

I`m new to build management and related dev ops stuff so please be gentle :) .
My team is working on an Android project and it depends on libraries such as Volley and the Facebook SDK.
Now Currently each developer has to import the libraries(from the official site) and manually add them to the build path and take care of library versions and the likes after checking out the android project.
I am looking for a solution where the developer can checkout the project, and the related libraries are also checked out automatically.
I would also like to specify the order of building the libs.

Another related issue:
One of the libraries almost always is not able to locate the JRE on every restart.(Manually adding the JRE fixes the issue...something tells me that a good build management flow will fix this)Suggestions on fixing this?
If you are suggesting a dependency management tool based solution id prefer Gradle based solutions.
Please suggest at least the high level flow I need to follow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would suggest `Gradle` + `git submodules` to keep the dependencies. Because some of the libraries are not available for `gradle` yet. So you have to change some structures, add some files to to become a  `Gradle` library.

Then, you can add your own libraries as `git submodule`s . Please take a lot about [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

It works for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches would be to have a separate folder in your repo, say "library", where you keep all library projects. Benefits:

- When a developer clones repo, he doesn't need to add libraries manually
- Everyone has the same set of libraries, no confusion when someone updates his lib, and other guy keeps older version.
- If you repo keeps track of libraries, than you easily restore environment for each release of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need a repository manager, like Nexus or Artifactory. This gives you one central, internal place to host the libraries. I haven't done this with gradle yet, but it works great with maven and should work pretty much the same way with gradle.